# Maven - repositories tag preventing deployment

Tags: maven, nexus

I have a project POM which specifies a repositories tag which points to a sandbox location.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>mysandbox</id>
        <name>Sandbox</name>
        <url>http://myTestingSite.com/repositories/sandbox/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

This works fine in Eclipse and resolves all dependencies however when i attempt to deploy i get the following exception.

```
   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (default-depl
    oy) on project myweb-web: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM insid
    e distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help
    1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plug
    ins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (default-deploy) on project myweb-web: Deployment failed: repos
    itory element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeployme
    ntRepository=id::layout::url parameter
```

Wrapping this in a Distributionmanagement element doesn't make any sense because I'm using the repository for dependency resolution and not deployment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error says you either don't have a `distributionManagement` element or the element isn't correct.

So this has nothing to do with the content of `<repositories>`. Just create a correct `distributionManagement` element and it will work.

Note that the broken element might be in the parent POM. Run `mvn help:effective-pom` to see the complete POM as Maven sees it.

Answer (score 6):

The repository that you have defined originally is only taken into consideration to download dependencies, not to upload them (as you mentioned).

What you need to add is a repository inside distribution management

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>id</id>
        <name>name</name>
        <url>nexus_url</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

And if your nexus is secured, you'll also need to define a server section for the password.

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>id</id>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```